# Create a scrollbar for a dom element without scrolling function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a formatted-json-html output.
To achieve that, am using this Plugin
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.json-viewer
demo : https://rawgit.com/abodelot/jquery.json-viewer/master/demo.html
It's working fine but if I add some objects to my JSON, lets say I change :

```
"topping": [
    { "id": 5001, "type": "None" },
    { "id": 5002, "type": "Glazed" },
    { "id": 5005, "type": "Sugar" },
    { "id": 5003, "type": "Chocolate" },
    { "id": 5004, "type": "Maple" }
  ]
```

to something like this:

```
"topping": [
    { "id": 5001, "type": "None" },
    { "id": 5002, "type": "Glazed" },
    { "id": 5005, "type": "Sugar" },
    { "id": 5003, "type": "Chocolate" },
    { "id": 5004, "type": "Maple" },
    { "id": 5004, "type": "Maple" },
    { "id": 5004, "type": "Maple" },
    { "id": 5004, "type": "Maple" },
    { "id": 5004, "type": "Maple" },
    { "id": 5004, "type": "Maple" },
    { "id": 5004, "type": "Maple" }
  ]
```

The height of the output gets changed.
So, basically just increasing the output, the entire output heights get changed. But I want to have a "fixed" height and add a scrollbar to it, if the output is too big for the height.
How would I achieve that?

EDIT :
Example of my program :
html div :

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

css:

```
output {
      min-height: 100px;
      max-height:100px;
      resize: none;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

JS: (setting some css settings there since there can be another kind of output)

```
function doStuff(outputVal) {
        var temp = JSON.parse(outputVal);
        $("#result").append('<pre id="output"></pre>');
        $('#output').css('background-color','white');
        $('#output').css('width','99.3%');
        $('#output').jsonViewer(temp);
}
```

Basically im having a button somewhere that calls the "doStuff" function with a JSON-String, the JSON String get parsed and an dom element gets created and im using the plugin that i linked earlier to create an formatted JSON output like in the example.  If i give an JSON-string that fits in a 100px height box (literally just 1 element) everything looks fine but if i give a long String the box height get increased or the text will go beyond the box(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oln8.jpg <- like here, its a bit small but if you look close you will see some brackets going over the output box).
Basically i want to use that plugin in to lets say output an 500 elements object as a JSON in a 100px height box with a scrollbar.
Sorry for my bad grammar or bad explanation, hopefully its still understandable somehow.

Also here are the sourcecode of the Plugin im using
https://github.com/abodelot/jquery.json-viewer/tree/master/json-viewer

Ive also tried to summary my problem into a single picture, maybe it will help a bit more.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxNLf.png

Comment: I would presume you can do this in CSS. Set a `height` (and `overflow`, if needed)

Comment: The height(and a min-height) is already set in css.   If i have a "big" area it will look like that https://i.imgur.com/F59sBJl.png and if i make it smaller https://imgur.com/AisQK6e the text will just go though the area. I have also added overflox-x:scroll to my css, doesnt change anything.

Comment: It would really help to see an example of the problem in your question. However you should note that it's `overflow-x`, not `overflox-x`

Comment: Yea overflow not overflox. Was an typing error. However i tried to add an example and some code snippets of my program im using. Hopfully its a bit easier to understand